# filter data based on conditions of another list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list with names.

```
name= ["John Lewis", "Michael Armstrong", "Kurt Abela","Brian Watson", "Gregory Dubois"]

name = pd.DataFrame(name)
```

I have a `pandas.DataFrame()` called `df`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Name':['Karan Singh,John Lewis', 'Michael Armstrong, Fabian Schreiber', 'Roy Dalhuisen', 'Arya Yildirim,Gregory Dubois'],
    'ID':[23,22,21,24]})
```

Now I would like to filter `df`, that only names which occured in `name` to also occur in `df` after filtering.

I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
df = df[~df.index.isin(name.index)
```

Comment: `name.index` is a function, not a list.

Comment: Just for clarification: The variable df is a dictionary or a pandas.DataFrame()?

Comment: @Jan I think it's the dictionary that he converts to a dataframe.

Comment: Can you show the resulting dataframe you want to get? `John Lewis` is in `name`, but `Karan Singh` is not. Should that row be in the result or not?

Comment: @Jan is a pandas.DataFrame()

Comment: @Maurice I've changed the post accordingly, now it is a DataFrame and not a dict anymore

Comment: @Jan thank you very much, name is also a dataframe

Comment: @Jan the problem is that all names in df have these []. but I cannot do that, otherwise stackoverflow deny to submit it, but it should be for all names like this ['Karan Singh,John Lewis']

Comment: @Maurice Please don't edit variable names in your post, otherwise the answers don't fit your post anymore.

Comment: @Jan okay sorry, but could you edit, that all names in df have this []

Comment: @Maurice In the screenshot, does the column 'Name' contain a string '[Karan Singh,John Lewis]' or a list of strings ['Karan Singh','John Lewis']?

Comment: it is dtype['o']

Comment: it contains  a list of string

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250550/discussion-between-maurice-and-jan).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use apply like this

```
import pandas as pd
df={'Name':[['Karan Singh,John Lewis'],['Michael Armstrong, Fabian Schreiber'],['Roy Dalhuisen'],['Arya Yildirim,Gregory Dubois'],["hh,bb"]],'ID':[23,22,21,24,28]}
#df to pandas
df = pd.DataFrame(df)

#union all the names and remove , 
all_names=[]
for name in df['Name'].values.tolist():
    all_names.extend(name[0].split(','))

print(all_names)

def filter_names(row):
    names = row.split(',')
    return any(name in names for name in all_names)

df_filtered = df[df['Name'].apply(filter_names)]
print(df_filtered)
```

Result

```
                                  Name  ID
0               Karan Singh,John Lewis  23
1  Michael Armstrong, Fabian Schreiber  22
2                        Roy Dalhuisen  21
3         Arya Yildirim,Gregory Dubois  24
4                                hh,bb  28

                                  Name  ID
0               Karan Singh,John Lewis  23
1  Michael Armstrong, Fabian Schreiber  22
3         Arya Yildirim,Gregory Dubois  24
```

Comment: @Maurice I have updated the answer. please check. Please accept if it answers your question.

Comment: last_name is the main name list.

Comment: @Maurice i didn't understood what are you talking about ? can you share some data or someting ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250549/discussion-between-hiren-namera-and-maurice).

Comment: @maurice updated answer for the dataframe you have.

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this:`filtered_df = df[df['Name'].isin(name)]`

Comment: Does that work when `df['Name']` is a comma-delimited string, not a single name?

Comment: it is not working because of comma-delimited string

Answer (score 0):

**Example**

```
name= ["John Lewis","Michael Armstrong","Kurt Abela","Brian Watson","Gregory Dubois"]
data = {'Name':['Karan Singh,John Lewis','Michael Armstrong, Fabian Schreiber','Roy Dalhuisen','Arya Yildirim,Gregory Dubois'],'ID':[23,22,21,24]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

`df`

```
    Name                                ID
0   Karan Singh,John Lewis              23
1   Michael Armstrong, Fabian Schreiber 22
2   Roy Dalhuisen                       21
3   Arya Yildirim,Gregory Dubois        24
```

---

i don know exact what you want.

**Code1**

```
 out = (df.assign(Name=df['Name'].str.split(','))
       .explode('Name')[lambda x: x['Name'].isin(name)])
```

`out`

```
    Name                ID
0   John Lewis          23
1   Michael Armstrong   22
3   Gregory Dubois      24
```

---

**Code2**

```
out = df[df['Name'].str.contains('|'.join(name))]
```

`out`

```
    Name                                ID
0   Karan Singh,John Lewis              23
1   Michael Armstrong, Fabian Schreiber 22
3   Arya Yildirim,Gregory Dubois        24
```

---

**Update**

```
name= ["John Lewis", "Michael Armstrong", "Kurt Abela","Brian Watson", "Gregory Dubois"]
name = pd.DataFrame(name)

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Name':[['Karan Singh','John Lewis'], ['Michael Armstrong', 'Fabian Schreiber'], ['Roy Dalhuisen'], ['Arya Yildirim', 'Gregory Dubois']],
    'ID':[23,22,21,24]})
```

`name`

```
    0
0   John Lewis
1   Michael Armstrong
2   Kurt Abela
3   Brian Watson
4   Gregory Dubois
```

`df`

```
    Name                                    ID
0   [Karan Singh, John Lewis]               23
1   [Michael Armstrong, Fabian Schreiber]   22
2   [Roy Dalhuisen]                         21
3   [Arya Yildirim, Gregory Dubois]         24
```

code

```
out = df[df['Name'].apply(lambda x: name[0].isin(x).sum() > 0)]
```

`out`

```
    Name                                    ID
0   [Karan Singh, John Lewis]               23
1   [Michael Armstrong, Fabian Schreiber]   22
3   [Arya Yildirim, Gregory Dubois]         24
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250552/discussion-on-answer-by-panda-kim-filter-data-based-on-conditions-of-another-lis).